# Imageview popup requesting internet image

Tags: android, popup, imageview

I want to show in my popup an image brought from the internet, i want to fill the imageview of the popup with the internet image, this is what i have done

```
private  boolean userClicked = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_serviciosp);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.publi);
    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("MY_URL");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);





    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                        = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                        popupView,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);



            }
        });
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            int x = random.nextInt(7) + 1;
            if (!userClicked && x == 1 || x == 3||  x == 5 )
                btnOpenPopup.performClick();
        }

    }, 100);

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Agro.this, web, desc, tel, imageId, imageId3);
    list = (ListView)

            findViewById(R.id.lvlista);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Agro.this, "Usted Clico en " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (position == 0) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:222222222222"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }


        }
    });
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

but it seems when i press the list it crash and it wont put the online image in the popup

thanks for the help

Comment: Please post the logcat output containing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use volley library for such network resources. Volley is efficient and works like a charm.

Comment: i use to this witouth such library, can you please help us with this code? thanks

Comment: There is a video in the above link.. that explains it all

Comment: i dont get the image to showup from the internet :/

Comment: Did you implement Volley properly, coz if you do, it surely would work. What error are you seeing ? - It is little interesting to get Volley working - it uses a singleton that has to be initialized globally so it works without blocking the UI thread